# Convert a "big" Hex number (string format) to a decimal number (string format) without BigInteger Class

Tags: c#, hex, biginteger, radix

How to convert a "big" Hex number (in string format):

> EC851A69B8ACD843164E10CFF70CF9E86DC2FEE3CF6F374B43C854E3342A2F1AC3E30C741CC41E679DF6D07CE6FA3A66083EC9B8C8BF3AF05D8BDBB0AA6CB3EF8C5BAA2A5E531BA9E28592F99E0FE4F95169A6C63F635D0197E325C5EC76219B907E4EBDCD401FB1986E4E3CA661FF73E7E2B8FD9988E753B7042B2BBCA76679

to a decimal number (in string format):

> 166089946137986168535368849184301740204613753693156360462575217560130904921953976324839782808018277000296027060873747803291797869684516494894741699267674246881622658654267131250470956587908385447044319923040838072975636163137212887824248575510341104029461758594855159174329892125993844566497176102668262139513

without using `BigInteger` Class (as my application should support machines without .NET Framework 4)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no simple way to do this.  I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: Write your own `BigInteger` implementation? Just using an existing thing (e.g. `BigInteger`) will be the easiest.

Comment: Use this as an inspiration? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532871/how-to-convert-a-very-large-hex-number-to-decimal-in-javascript

Comment: I voted to close because you exclude the obvious solution with no reasoning behind this decision. Too localized.

Comment: @spender
Don't you think that suggesting an edit for this was better than suggesting a "close" ?

Comment: What is the reason turning this into a base 10 number?

Comment: @Krumelur Thanks it seems to the point.

Comment: @CSharpie The application I'm writing itself is an unlimited numerical converter.

Comment: This might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36323/BigInt

Comment: seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. Maybe its so long it can't all be loaded into memory (:-S)

Comment: @HeshamERAQI nobody but you could've given the reason you wanted to not use `BigInteger`. Now that you've supplied that, I think the question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @TimS.
Douglas answer proved that implementing `BigInteger` class was not the easiest solution though :)

Comment: @HeshamERAQI No, but using an existing one, built-in to the .NET framework you were using, would have been. Glad you got a simple solution in the end. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty implementation that can work with arbitrarily-large numbers. The aim of this implementation is simplicity, not performance; thus, it should be optimized drastically if it's to be used in a production scenario.

**Edit**: Simplified further per Dan Byström's implementation of the inverse [decimal-to-hex conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653006/1149773):

```
static string HexToDecimal(string hex)
{
    List<int> dec = new List<int> { 0 };   // decimal result

    foreach (char c in hex)
    {
        int carry = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 16);   
            // initially holds decimal value of current hex digit;
            // subsequently holds carry-over for multiplication

        for (int i = 0; i < dec.Count; ++i)
        {
            int val = dec[i] * 16 + carry;
            dec[i] = val % 10;
            carry = val / 10;
        }

        while (carry > 0)
        {
            dec.Add(carry % 10);
            carry /= 10;
        }
    }

    var chars = dec.Select(d => (char)('0' + d));
    var cArr = chars.Reverse().ToArray();
    return new string(cArr);
}
```

Comment: Why is the `dec` list starting with a `0` in it?

Comment: @TimothyShields: It's meant as the initial value of the decimal result, but it's redundant in all cases where the hex input is non-empty. I'll remove it.

Comment: Which string did you test? The code produces the correct result for the OP's number.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't know the command line input had a limit, was cutting off two strings from the OP's input.

Comment: @Douglas
This is what I call a beautiful solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Most of the credit would be due to [Dan Byström](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652760/how-to-convert-a-gi-normous-integer-in-string-format-to-hex-format-c/2653006#2653006); I just reversed his conversion. Glad to help :-)

Comment: @TimothyShields: I've just realized that the `dec` list needs to be initialized to contain `0` to handle cases where the input hexadecimal is `"0"`, as the final result would otherwise be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I just translated Douglas code to JAVA:

```
public static String HexToDec(String hex) {
    List<Integer> dec = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int k = 0; k < hex.length(); k++) {
        String c = hex.charAt(k) + "";
        int carry = Integer.parseInt(c, 16);

        for (int i = 0; i < dec.size(); ++i) {
            int val = dec.get(i) * 16 + carry;
            dec.set(i, val % 10);
            carry = val / 10;
        }

        while (carry > 0) {
            dec.add(carry % 10);
            carry /= 10;
        }
    }

    int[] out = new int[dec.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < dec.size(); i++) {
        out[i] = dec.get(i).intValue();
    }

    return arrayToDecString(reverseArray(out));

}

public static String arrayToDecString(int[] data) {

    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        str += data[i] + "";
    }
    return str;
}

public static int[] reverseArray(int[] data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[data.length - i - 1];
        data[data.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just translated Douglas' code into VBA

```
Function HexToDecimal(ByVal sHex As String) As String

    Dim dec() As Long
    ReDim dec(0 To 0) As Long

    Dim lCharLoop As Long
    For lCharLoop = 1 To Len(sHex)

        Dim char As String * 1
        char = Mid$(sHex, lCharLoop, 1)

        Dim carry As Long
        carry = Val("&h" & char)

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To UBound(dec)
            Dim lVal As Long
            lVal = dec(i) * 16 + carry
            dec(i) = lVal Mod 10
            carry = lVal \ 10
        Next i

        While (carry > 0)
            ReDim Preserve dec(0 To UBound(dec) + 1) As Long
            dec(UBound(dec)) = carry Mod 10
            carry = carry \ 10
        Wend
    Next

    For lCharLoop = UBound(dec) To LBound(dec) Step -1
        Dim sDecimal As String
        sDecimal = sDecimal & Chr$(48 + dec(lCharLoop))

    Next

    HexToDecimal = sDecimal

End Function

Private Sub TestHexToDecimal()

    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("F") = "15"
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("4") = CStr(Val("&H4"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("10") = CStr(Val("&H10"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("20") = CStr(Val("&H20"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("30") = CStr(Val("&H30"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("40") = CStr(Val("&H40"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("44") = CStr(Val("&H44"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("FF") = "255"
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("FFF") = "4095"
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("443") = CStr(Val("&H443"))
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("443C1") = "279489"
    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("443C1CE20DFD592FB374D829B894BBE5") = "90699627342249584016268008583970733029"

    Debug.Assert HexToDecimal("EC851A69B8ACD843164E10CFF70CF9E86DC2FEE3CF6F374B43C854E3342A2F1AC3E30" & _
    "C741CC41E679DF6D07CE6FA3A66083EC9B8C8BF3AF05D8BDBB0AA6CB3EF8C5BAA2A5" & _
    "E531BA9E28592F99E0FE4F95169A6C63F635D0197E325C5EC76219B907E4EBDCD401FB1" & _
    "986E4E3CA661FF73E7E2B8FD9988E753B7042B2BBCA76679") = _
    "1660899461379861685353688491843017402046137536931563604625752175601309049219" & _
    "5397632483978280801827700029602706087374780329179786968451649489474169926767" & _
    "4246881622658654267131250470956587908385447044319923040838072975636163137212" & _
    "8878242485755103411040294617585948551591743298921259938445664971761026682621" & _
    "39513"

End Sub
```

Also a benchmark at [statman.info Hexadecimal Conversion for large numbers](http://www.statman.info/conversions/hexadecimal.php)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use a big number library that supports your version of .NET. I'd recommend [GnuMpDotNet](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/), which uses the excellent [GMP library](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://gmplib.org/&ei=P7WwUcmoDYrrrQHC74DwDQ&usg=AFQjCNGTj9nbH_SqEFtUF4hmNqeVkHOYrw&sig2=VHpn5x9XtTmGCcd3fJy-ZQ&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aWM). By default it targets .NET 3.5, but you can change that to .NET 2.0 without breaking anything (just remove the references and `using` statement that refer to new things), as it doesn't use anything from .NET 3.5.  Here is an example using GnuMpDotNet:

```
BigInt e = new BigInt(hexString, 16);
string decimalStr = e.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IntX](https://github.com/devoyster/IntXLib) library as it should work with .Net 2.0 and up. From the description on the page in regards to `BigInteger`:

> So internally System.Numerics.BigInteger seems to use standard
>   arbitrary arithmetic algorithms and I am not worrying about IntX
>   library since, due to its use of FHT, it can be times faster for
>   really big integers.

The license is pretty liberal but worth reading first just to make sure it's okay.

I've not used this library but from a cursory glance at the source code this should be all you need to do

```
string dec = new IntX(myHex, 16).ToString();
```

If you don't want to compile the code yourself, you can install it via Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231860/2521214

worth looking

- string based conversions (limited by free memory only)
- dec->hex and hex<-dec  included
- no bigint/bigreal lib used
- supporting fixed point string formats (no exponents)

Answer (score 0):

I just translated Douglas code to PHP:

```
function BigNumberHexToDecimal($hex)
{
    $dec = array(0);
    $hexLen = strlen($hex);
    for($h=0;$h<$hexLen;++$h)
    {
        $carry = hexdec($hex[$h]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dec); ++$i)
        {
            $val = $dec[$i] * 16 + $carry;
            $dec[$i] = $val % 10;
            $carry = (int)($val / 10);
        }
        while ($carry > 0)
        {
            $dec[] = $carry % 10;
            $carry = (int)($carry / 10);
        }
    }

    return join("", array_reverse($dec));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just translated Douglas code to Delphi/Pascal:

```
function HexToDecimal(const Hex: string): string;
var
  dec: TList;
  I: Integer;
  carry: Cardinal;
  c: Char;
  val: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  dec := TList.Create;
  try
    dec.Add(Pointer(0));          // decimal result

    for c in Hex do begin
      carry := StrToInt('$' + c); // initially holds decimal value of current hex digit;
                                  // subsequently holds carry-over for multiplication
      for I := 0 to dec.Count -1 do begin
        val := Integer(dec[I]) * 16 + carry;
        dec[I] := Pointer(Integer(val mod 10));
        carry := val div 10;
      end;

      while carry > 0 do begin
        dec.Add(Pointer(Integer(carry mod 10)));
        carry := carry div 10;
      end;
    end;

    for I := 0 to dec.Count -1 do begin
      val := Integer(dec[I]);
      Result := IntToStr(val) + Result;
    end;
  finally
    dec.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := HexToDecimal('FF'); // 255
  S := HexToDecimal('FFF'); // 4095
  S := HexToDecimal('443C1'); // 279489
  S := HexToDecimal('443C1CE20DFD592FB374D829B894BBE5'); // "90699627342249584016268008583970733029"
  S := 'EC851A69B8ACD843164E10CFF70CF9E86DC2FEE3CF6F374B43C854E3342A2F1AC3E30' +
    'C741CC41E679DF6D07CE6FA3A66083EC9B8C8BF3AF05D8BDBB0AA6CB3EF8C5BAA2A5' +
    'E531BA9E28592F99E0FE4F95169A6C63F635D0197E325C5EC76219B907E4EBDCD401FB1' +
    '986E4E3CA661FF73E7E2B8FD9988E753B7042B2BBCA76679';
  S := HexToDecimal(S); // "166089946137986168535368849184301740204613753693156360462575217560130904921953976324839782808018277000296027060873747803291797869684516494894741699267674246881622658654267131250470956587908385447044319923040838072975636163137212887824248575510341104029461758594855159174329892125993844566497176102668262139513"
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Translated Douglas code to Qt:

```
QByteArray convertHexToDecimal(const QByteArray &hex)
{
    QList<int> dec;
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.count(); i++) {
        int carry = hex.mid(i, 1).toInt(nullptr, 16);
        for (int j = 0; j < dec.count(); ++j) {
            int val = dec[j] * 16 + carry;
            dec[j] = val % 10;
            carry = val / 10;
        }

        while (carry > 0) {
            dec.append(carry % 10);
            carry /= 10;
        }
    }

    QByteArray chars;
    foreach (int d, dec) {
        chars.prepend((char)('0' + d));
    }

    return chars;
}
```