# How to create an RSA key from hex-encoded modulus and encrypt in node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa

I'm finding the way to RSA encryption in node.js, I want to handle big numbers, so I use this: https://github.com/eschnou/node-bignumber

What I'm going to do is just encryption, with modulus and exponent. I don't have to do decryption. anyway, I got an error on and on, but I don't know what's wrong. Can anyone know what it is wrong? Thanks.

**Code**

```
require("node-bignumber");
var nvalue="ad6eb61316ff805e9c94667ab04aa45aa3203eef71ba8c12afb353a5c7f11657e43f5ce4483d4e6eca46af6b3bde4981499014730d3b233420bf3ecd3287a2768da8bd401f0abd7a5a137d700f0c9d0574ef7ba91328e9a6b055820d03c98d56943139075d";
var evalue="010001";
var encpw="";
var rsa = new RSAKey;

function encryptMessage() {
    var message = "All your bases are belong to us.";
    rsa.setPublic(evalue, nvalue);
    encpw.value = rsa.encrypt(message);
    console.log(encpw);
}

encryptMessage();
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: RSAKey is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\win\Desktop\untitled\juntae.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

[image]

Comment: The packaged version of JSBN doesn't seem to contain `RSAKey`. Have you seen the [usage guidance](https://github.com/eschnou/node-bignumber#usage)? Anyway, if you just want to do RSA encryption, then you should really use the built-in [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Actually 3 days ago I jumped in Nodejs from weak base javascript. I think there is RSAKey constructor on lib/rsa/rsa.js, But I don't know how to use it. I changed RSAKey to another from usage guidance, but I don't know about it... It's so difficult to me to understand, I don't know why they use hex value on modulus and exponent.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I red nodejs api that you recommend (crypto module), there is a fucntion for RSA encryption. **crypto.publicEncrypt(public_key, buffer)**. right? But the parameter, I don't understand with it. I think public key should be a pair. (mod and exp) but why parameter get just one public key? and is buffer an message to encryption. right? So I don't know how can I do... I searched whole day on with this simple problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to load an RSA public key from modulus and public exponent in this way:

```
var rsa = require("node-bignumber");

var n = "ad6eb61316ff805e9c94667ab04aa45aa3203eef71ba8c12afb353a5c7f11657e43f5ce4483d4e6eca46af6b3bde4981499014730d3b233420bf3ecd3287a2768da8bd401f0abd7a5a137d700f0c9d0574ef7ba91328e9a6b055820d03c98d56943139075d";
var e = "010001";
var pub = new rsa.Key();
pub.setPublic(n, e);

var message = "Message";
var encrypted = pub.encrypt(message);

console.log(encrypted);
```

The public key in RSA consists of the modulus and the public exponent, because both values are needed during encryption.

Comment: Can I ask last one question... I did copy your code and tried to run it, but "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPublic' of undefined**" this error returned.  I want to giveup nodejs. I don't know what it is wrong... There is **RSAKey.prototype.setPublic = RSASetPublic**; and then RSASetPublic is exist. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `new`.

Comment: For others who read this and are using a different library, you may need to modify to var n = "00ad63..."  some implementation will (correctly) treat this as a negative number.  I have not used this library, I assume it behaves as expected with the code above.

Comment: @MikeF Good point. The big number library inside of the node module is capable of representing negative numbers, but I haven't actually checked whether it calculates with negative numbers. It would be quite strange in the context of RSA. Anyway, you also need to check whether the library expects the hex-encoded number in big-endian or little-endian format, meaning the "00" might need to go to the back of the modulus.